# Finding current location by geolocation on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, windows-7, safari, geolocation

I have a Safari browser on Windows 7,

In my site I use Geolocation to find current location

in Chrome and FireFox it works

in Safari it crashes.

I read that Safari does not support Geolocation **without Wifi**, is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari on Wifi does not seem to be the most accurate method of geolocation for some people.

As to Safari crashing, you should put a timeout so that the script has a way to fail without crashing.  Let it fall back to error handler.

The following might help
    { maximumAge: 600000, timeout: 8000 }

Also, you can test some demos first to see what results you will get with different browsers.

http://html5demos.com/geo
W3C - http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

It can cause problems in Safari as they use a different service. You also might need to turn on the feature to first use it. Try enabling the location services in Safari. Go to Preferences->Security and check "Allow websites to ask for location information". Also, make sure System Preferences->Security does not have "Disable Location Services" checked.

Comment: If I give him a timeout, it will fall on Getting current position, I need him to identify the location, there is no way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but other things are most likely at play here.  You do however don't want the browser crashing on you.

Comment: All the site based on the current location, so most things will fall without identifying the current location

Comment: My question is: Is there another way to identify current location in the safari without wifi

Comment: It can cause problems in Safari as they use a different service.  You also might need to turn on the feature to first use it.  Try enabling the location services in Safari.

Go to Preferences->Security and check "Allow websites to ask for location information". Also, make sure System Preferences->Security does not have "Disable Location Services" checked.

Comment: Yes I have enable the browser settings but still its not working.

Any other way to do this in safari?